Mapping pattern and correct codes to install a library/package in Python that only targets the functions within a code
I'm trying to generate a local library/package that only has the functions that exist within the code, but when I try to use from .my_functions import * as the __init__ default, when installing and trying to use it in a new code, not only the functions that are in the code appear, but also the code itself that also gives access to the same functions. Let's see!
Initial note: the number of functions in the code will change over time and the name of the functions will also change, so I want a way to not have to list each function name for __init__, I want to use a way that collects all the functions without specifying them one by one, so I tried to use *.
File map:
my_library/
│
├── my_library/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_functions.py
│
└── setup.py


__init__.py:
from .my_functions import *

my_functions.py:
def send_hi():
    print("Hi!")

def send_bye():
    print("Bye!")

def send_go():
    print("Go!")

setup.py:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="my_library",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
)

Installation using pip in the my_library/ folder exactly where we have the setup.py file:
pip install .

Current result:


Expected result (note that there is no option to access the file containing the functions, only the functions):


Short answer: You can't. That it simply how Python imports work. -- Long answer: Python's meta-programming abilities are very permissive, so maybe there is a way (personally I do not know any solution, but I am quite sure there has to be at least one), but I doubt it will be worth the effort. If it were me I would just offer the API from my_library.my_functions import send_bye and be done with it, I doubt users will care or should care. That's just how Python is, I do not see the point in trying to modify this, hide details.

A sort-of solution that doesn't really work
I'm not sure why you want to do this, but it's actually fairly simple
to do (but not really, see below). All the local variables in a module are stored in a dict that you can access via the locals() function. If you delete an entry from there, it won't be visible anymore.
So your my_library/__init__.py would look like this:
from .my_functions import *
del locals()["my_functions"]

Unfortunately, while this makes using my_library.my_functions impossible (you get the error AttributeError: module 'my_library' has no attribute 'my_functions'), VSCode fails to notice it's been removed and still autocompletes as before.
So in the end, @sinoroc is right, you can't really do what you want.
The more pythonic solution
Now, if what you're trying to do is tell the caller they're supposed to use the functions, but not the sub-module, the pythonic way to do that is the start the name with an underscore. Anything with an underscore means "this is internal, don't try to use it, it might change without warning".
So if you call the file _my_functions.py, autocompletetion will still have {} _my_functions but users should understand they're not supposed to use it because of that underscore.
After thought
And if you combine that with del locals()["_my_functions"] their code will fail if they use my_library._my_functions and thus you'll be sure they'll respect your intent. Mind you, they can still import my_library._my_functions if they want.
